# C# .NET Checking if browser is mobile - what is the most reliable way?

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser, mobile

I know I can use `Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice`.

But does anyone know how it works, and if it is reliable and up to date?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for this. Put it in a folder in the `App_Browsers` folder. http://mdbf.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks Daniel. So all I need to do is create the folder /App_Browsers/Devices, put mobile.browser in there, and use Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice as usual and it will now be using the new definition (Feb 2010 which I downloaded). Is that right?

Comment: Yep. Thats all. Theres a ton of other caps there too.

Answer (score 3):

You need to regularly update BrowserCaps to keep it up-to-date.

http://www.asp.net/mobile/device-updates/instructions/

Note: (Aug 25 2012) apparently the page has been removed.

Comment: Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice is relied on BrowserCaps

Comment: That looks pretty out of date.

Comment: Now 404's. Unable to find a newer resource on ASP.NET.

Comment: This answer is outdated. The provided URL no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

And if you need some more advance and mature, then try [WURFL](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: WURFL is still around in 2018...impressive!

Answer (score 1):

This question needed some 2018 love. Try this.

```
if(Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice){
// do something
}
```

You shouldn't need any `@using` statements for this, but if you did Intellisense would you tell and help you add it with a click.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use the latest and greatest features available you should take a look into the [IE9 demo](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/85CSS3_MediaQueries/Default.html) for [Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) to make your decision by checking the current screen resolution.