# How to detect client is on computer or mobile?

Tags: asp.net, browser

In ASP.NET with C# to redirect page to Normal version or Mobile version how can I detect whether client is in computer browser or mobile phone browser?

Also how to detect mobile phone's screen resolution.

Comment: look at the User-Agent value in the HTTP header and look to see if it's a mobile browser or not and do redirection on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice
```

Also I don't believe you can get the screen res from the server side.

You can get it with javascript though

`screen.width` `screen.height`
I suppose you could feed that back in through an ajax call....

Answer (score 1):

u can check it with

```
 Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice
```

also check following link

[C# .NET Checking if browser is mobile - what is the most reliable way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451540/c-sharp-net-checking-if-browser-is-mobile-what-is-the-most-reliable-way)