# How to detect whether web application is running from mobile device or system in asp.net?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a .NET MVC4 (Aspx View) application.

I would like to apply different functionality in case application is running from mobile device so it is necessary for me to know from which device application is running.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# .NET Checking if browser is mobile - what is the most reliable way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451540/c-sharp-net-checking-if-browser-is-mobile-what-is-the-most-reliable-way)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to check if request is coming from mobile device. Like:

```
    public bool IsMobileSite()
    {
        try
        {
                var HttpUserAgent = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];

                // Create regex to filter the mobile browsers
                var FilterFirst =
                    new Regex(
                        @"android.+mobile|avantgo|bada\\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile
                                |ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge|maemo|midp|mmp|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\\/|plucker
                                |pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino",
                        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);

                var FilterSecond =
                    new Regex(@"1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\\-)|ai(ko|rn)
                                |al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)
                                |bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\\-(n|u)|c55\\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\\-|co(mp|nd)
                                |craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8
                                |ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\\-5|g\\-mo|go(\\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit
                                |hd\\-(m|p|t)|hei\\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\\-c|ht(c(\\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\\-(20|go|ma)
                                |i230|iac( |\\-|\\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\\/)|klon
                                |kpt |kwc\\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\\-|e\\/|\\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\\-w|m3ga|m50\\/
                                |ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\\-| |o|v)|zz)
                                |mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)
                                |nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\\-2
                                |po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\\-g|qa\\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\\-[2-7]|i\\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)
                                |s55\\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\\-|oo|p\\-)|sdk\\/|se(c(\\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\\-|shar|sie(\\-|m)|sk\\-0
                                |sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\\-|v\\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\\-
                                |tdg\\-|tel(i|m)|tim\\-|t\\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\\-|m3|m5)|tx\\-9|up(\\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)
                                |vk(40|5[0-3]|\\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700
                                |xda(\\-|2|g)|yas\\-|your|zeto|zte\\-",
                              RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {

        }

        return ((HttpUserAgent != null && FilterFirst.IsMatch(HttpUserAgent)) ||
                        (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(HttpUserAgent) && HttpUserAgent.Length >= 4 &&
                         FilterSecond.IsMatch(HttpUserAgent.Substring(0, 4))));
    }
```